# Label and input wrapping at different widths

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have, in one row, three columns, the first two with text (titles), and the last one with a label/select input stacked one on top of the other. What I want to do is to make columns wrap at different widths - specifically, the label/select at `md`, and the text-only ones at `sm`. Seems simple, but I can't make the label and the select wrap at the same time. The select breaks at `md` as expected, but the label wraps only at `sm` width, together with the titles.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <h2>Large title</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <h3>Smaller, longer title</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="sel">Select an option</label>
      <select id="sel" name="sel" class="form-control">
        <option>First option with long text</option>
        <option>Second option with long text</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uft4vaoc/

Am I doing anything stupid here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want, see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/uft4vaoc/1/

just add `col-xs-12` to the div you want to wrap together like this:

`<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">`

And to give it a nicer flow, you could add some extra classes like this example https://jsfiddle.net/uft4vaoc/3/

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-6  col-xs-8">
      <label for="sel">Select an option</label>
      <select id="sel" name="sel" class="form-control">
        <option>First option with long text</option>
        <option>Second option with long text</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well I didn't understand why it works, but it works. hahaha
Thanks!

Comment: @FabioPereira it would be best to read the bootstrap doc's. Basically bootstrap is mobile first design so it usually opposite of the way you learn about breakpoints. `md-3` say anything above `md` do this, but what you were missing was the `xs`, `xs` will do something until the page gets to `md` then it will use the `md` class. (did i just over complicate that?)

Comment: @FabioPereira it would be good for you to read from here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid down